# Save and load integer score in different view controllers

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I've got 3 view controllers, and I have a int called Count on each one. Count is the high score of the user, and that is what I want to preserve even when the app gets killed.

This is the integer;

```
int Count = 100;
```

This is where the score shows up(A UILabel inside ViewDiDLoad);

```
scoreCounter.text = @"";
```

And this is the code that I call it with(Inside IBAction);

```
NSString *numValue = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%d", Count--];
scoreCounter.text = numValue;
[numValue release];
```

Basically every time I press the button, the score will go down. I have the code above in three different view controllers, that opens like this;

```
if(Count == 90)
{
    SecondLevelViewController *screen = [[SecondLevelViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    screen.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
    [self presentModalViewController:screen animated:YES];
    [screen release];
```

What I need is a way to save this score, and to save which view controller that was last used, so that if the score is 90, the app will launch the SecondViewController.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSUserDefaults` is useful for this.

To save:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:Count forKey:@"Count"];
```

To load:

```
Count = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"Count"];
```

Since initially there is no value, your first load will give you 0 instead of 100. This can be dealt with by setting a default.

```
NSDictionary *defaults = @{ @"Count" : @100 };
[[NSUserDefault standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:defaults];
```

Add this code to your app startup such as in the app delegate `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method.

Comment: Great! But where should I put these? Both of them in the ViewDidLoad?

Comment: Put the code to load the value in `viewDidLoad`. Put the code to save the value at the point you change the value of `Count`.

Comment: Another option for the place to put the code to load the value is in the appropriate `init...` method.

Comment: I put the load in the viewDidLoad and the save in the IBAction it now saves, but I get a negative number when pressing?

Comment: The initial load will give you 0 since initially there is no value stored. and then you subtract 1 so you get -1. Why not start at zero and up to 100 instead of starting at 100 and going down?

Comment: Oh ok, it's suposed to be a countdown. Is it possible to start at 100 and go down?